# Using Moles to mock static constructor - user-defined breakpoint encountered

Tags: c#, static, moles

I'm using Moles in a legacy project where I need to mock out a class with a static constructor which does something I don't want it to in a testing environment. No problem - MolesEraseStaticConstructor attribute to the rescue, right? Well, not quite...

When I try to run my tests, I get a pop-up saying: "Microsoft.Moles.VsHost has encountered a user defined breakpoint." with the description: "A breakpoint in an application indicates a program error. After this dialog is dismissed, the application will continue running, but it may be in an unstable state."

The last part of the message is true: If I choose "Close", sometimes the test fails and sometimes it doesn't - and yet other times it gets aborted.

If I choose Debug, I go to some assembly code I can't figure out where originates.

How can I figure out more about what' going wrong here?

(A little aside-question: I tried to mock out a class inside the static constructor to try and get around it that way, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I right is assuming that you can't mock something inside a static constructor with Moles?)

Comment: Did you by any chance solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem as well.

I had an #ifdef DEBUG, and inside of it, a call to System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()

So... there really was a user-defined breakpoint. How silly of me!